# Radio Transmission

Tags: pi-3, remote, radio, assembly

Yes, I pretty much a noob, but I was wondering if there is a way to program the Raspberry Pi in Assembly Code to transmit data via radio frequencies (like remote control) between itself and another Raspberry Pi. Specifically the Raspberry Pi 3  B v1.2.

Comment: Use Bluetooth or plain old WiFi. They're easy, safe and legal.

Comment: Thanks, but, what I am specifically trying to do is have three emitters (most likely Raspberry Pi devices) give off signals, each with an identifier. Then have the Raspberry Pi record how long it took for the signal to reach it to figure its position.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it is possible to program the Raspberry Pi in Assembly Code. Just use an assembler. What you wrote in your comment before is not part of the question. You should edit the question and insert it.

Comment: Most folks do that with Bluetooth beacons.

Comment: Adafruit sells a bunch of [RF transceivers](https://www.adafruit.com/category/883) that work on legal frequencies (make sure you get one that uses legal frequencies in your country) that you can connect to a Pi using the GPIO pins. As for using assembly language... well, you can, but *why*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your country's laws regarding wireless transmission systems. You need to make sure that you're not exceeding any limits in terms of, for example, power transmission, and that you are not operating in a band for which you have not been granted permission. The bottom line is: before you start building anything, research and make sure that your design does not break any laws. The examples I just mention do not cover all the aspects you need to consider before building a radio system. This website is not meant to provide legal advice, it is meant to offer technical support. With that said, I cannot take any responsibility for what you build.

Now, on to the technical issues in hand. Programming the RPi in Assembly language is a big challenge. There are a couple of online resources that I will suggest: [Introduction to Computer Organization: ARM Assembly Language Using the Raspberry Pi](http://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/frontmatter-1.html) and [ARM Assembler in Raspberry Pi](https://thinkingeek.com/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi/).

If you look specifically at this [example code](http://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/exercises-34.html) to blink an LED using Assembly language you'll see the challenges that it entails. Once you understand how to do this you can move on to sending out radio messages. The next challenge is building a receptor and being able to decode them.